# Factoring $x^{2n} +2 x^n \cos{na\pi}+1$ polynomial

Tags: polynomials

I have a very strange polynomial to factorize and can't even get started with it, so if anyone could give me a hint on how to get started, not the exact solution.

$$x^{2n} +2 x^n \cos{na\pi}+1$$ 
where $a$ is an irrational number.

Comment: you want to factorize it into what?

Comment: Well, judging from the other tasks in my textbook -> a product of  something

Comment: Can you solve the quadratic $y^2+2ky+1 =0$?

Comment: Yes, I can, but I am not sure why is it important for $a$ to be irrational? Is it so I couldn't transform the $i\sin{na\pi}+ \cos{na\pi}$ to exponential form of a complex number? ( I am asking this since this was a test question, and they might have used that to lure students into  making a mistake)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
x^{2n}+2x^n\cos na\pi+1&=(x^n+1)^2-2x^n\left(1-\cos na\pi\right)\\
&=(x^n+1)^2-2x^n(2\sin^2\frac{na\pi}{2})\\
&=(x^n+1)^2-4x^n\sin^2\left(na\pi/2\right)\\
&=\left[x^n+2x^{n/2}\sin \left(na\pi/2\right)+1\right]\left[x^n-2x^{n/2}\sin \left(na\pi/2\right)+1\right]
\end{align*}